# Error while angular unit testing with Jasmine and Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have already imported the angular material in my spec.ts but I am getting the below error when trying to run the test that is ng test of this particular component:

Error: Template parse errors:

'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

[ERROR ->]
                          
                      ][dataSource]="parts" matSort  class="mat-elevation-z8">
                    
                "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/PartViewComponent.html@6:23
                The pipe 'uuidAbbrev' could not be found ("eader-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Uuid
                       {{[ERROR ->]row.uuid|uuidAbbrev}}
                    
                "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/PartViewComponent.html@10:44
                Can't bind to 'matHeaderRowDef' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("
                    
                    ]*matHeaderRowDef="displayedProps">
                    
                    [ERROR ->]
                    
                    ]*matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedProps;">
                  
                
                "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/PartViewComponent.html@24:35
                Property binding matRowDefColumns not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
                    
                    [ERROR ->]
                  
                http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:36418:17)
                    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:54593:19)
                    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:60159:37)
                    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:60146:23)
                    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:60089:62
                    at Set.forEach ()
                    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:60089:19)
                    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:60007:19
                    at Object.then (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:36409:77)
                    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:60005:26)*
            ```

Comment: Share some code, what does your test look like?

Comment: All the required details are added :

1. My test file (spec.ts)
2. The component.ts file which is to be tested
3.  The error encountered when the test case is executed.

Comment: I believe you need to add the material component modules to your imports array in `TestBed.configureTestingModule()`

Comment: The test cases are still dailing. could you please help me with a valid test case for the above written .ts file?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

To avoid importing modules from Angular Material directly you need to create a separated Angular module. This is a good practice, and you should stick to it :)

Second,
You need to import the Angular Material module you just create in your TestBed:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              imports: [MaterialModule],
              declarations: [PartViewComponent],
              providers: [PartService]
            })
            .compileComponents();
          }));
```

Example of my MaterialModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatExpansionModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatExpansionModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

Last but not least, probably you'll get another error related to pipe `uuidAbbrev`, make sure to add it to your **declarations** array in the `TestBed.configureTestingModule`

Comment: Can you please explain why this is a good practice? It does not seem clear, why we would want to include ALL modules when we just may need 1 in PartViewComponent. Are there dependencies? And in production (not testing), doesn't this blow up the resulting code? I am unarare, how "imports" really works.

Comment: Ah, back in the days it was recommended to do it in such a way to avoid importing the same module over and over again. For example, importing the MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, etc. in all your modules. However, I can see that this guy here https://indepth.dev/posts/1191/stop-using-shared-material-module recommends stopping doing so.
Ideally, tree-shaking should be able to strip all unused imports from the shared MaterialModule.  I'll need to give it a try and compare.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate reply and the link!